# url that worked with urllib.open does not with requests.get

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a script that used to work with urllib and now has to use requests. I have a url I use to put stuff in a database. the url is

http://www.example.com/insert.php?network=testnet&id=1245100&c=2800203&lat=7555344

this url worked through urllib(urlopen) but i get 403 forbidden when doing it through requests.get

```
HEADER = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.61 Safari/537.36' }

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update = ( HEADER,)
payload={'network':'testnet','id':'1245300','c':'2803824', 'lat':'7555457'}

response = requests.get("http://www.example.com/insert.php", headers=headers, params=payload)
print(f"Remote commit: {response.text}")
print(response.url)
```

the url works in a browser and gets a simple json ok response.

the script produces:

```
Remote commit: <html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

http://www.example.com/insert.php?network=testnet&id=1245300&c=2803824&lat=7555457
```

not sure what I am doing wrong.

edit: changed https to http.

Answer (score 0):

Forbidden often correlated to SSL/TLS certificate verification failure. Please try using the `requests.get` by setting the `verify=False` as following

Fixing the SSL certificate issue

```
requests.get("https://www.example.com/insert.php?network=testnet&id=1245300&c=2803824&lat=7555457", verify=False)
```

Fixing the TLS certificate issue
Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72347165/python-requests-403-forbidden-error-while-downlaoding-pdf-file-from-www-resear/72349915#72349915) related to the TLS certificate verification fix.

Comment: actually the url isn't supposed to be https, same thing happens with http.

Answer (score -1):

Somehow I overcomplicated it and when I tried the absolute minimum that works.

```
import requests

headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.61 Safari/537.36' }

response = requests.get("http://www.example.com/insert.php?network=testnet&id=1245200&c=2803824&lat=7555457", headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```